# XMLHttpRequest not work in my extension chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

**I'm trying to useXMLHttpRequest in a google chrome extension, but the results are not satisfactory, it does not work**

```
  {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TESTE",
    "description": "Reader",
    "version": "10.1.11",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "40",
    "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches" : [
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
      ],
        "js" : ["meu.js"],
        "run_at" : "document_end",
        "all_frames" : true
    }],
    "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://*/",
    "http://*/"
    ]

  }

function fdata()
{
 http = false;
      /* For Firefox*/    
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
         http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else /*For IE*/
         if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
            try {
                /*For some versions of IE*/
                http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                  /*For some other versions of IE*/
                  http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
         }
      }
      if (!http) {
         alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
         return false;
     }

    var url = "http://191.xxx.xxx.xxx/02082018001/add_m.php";
    var params = "l_data=teste";

    http.open('POST', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");   

    http.send(params);
}
```

I'm trying to useXMLHttpRequest in a google chrome extension, but the results are not satisfactory, it does not work

Comment: Do it in the [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), not in the content script.

Comment: Obrigado ! Thanks !!!